# spring-json vs jackson for spring framework 3.0.5

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm about to choose a JSON library to a spring based application and want to get some pros and cons for both solutions. Of course **conditional** pros and cons are well seen :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If performance matters, there is nothing on Java platform that comes even close to Jackson with respect to performance (see [this](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers), [this](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/01/entry_437.html) or [this](http://www.martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/) as initial data points).
Some newer libraries  (such as "json-smart") claim to be lightweight, fast(er), but have no external verification; most often since their own results do not follow [performance measurement best practices](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/04/entry_454.html). So to know performance details for your specific use case, do test them with your own data and see how things go, in addition to doing bit of googling.

Other than performance, there's [this blog post](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/11/entry_434.html) ("7 Jackson killer features") that outlines what Jackson has to offer on its own (not considering integration with frameworks) -- other libraries have their own strengths, and for [flex-json](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) I understand its output side (writing JSON) is quite flexible and powerful. And if you absolutely want to minimize JSON library (jar) size, ["Stringtree"](http://www.stringtree.org/stringtree-json.html) and [GSON-streaming](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming) are decent choices (but do not offer data-binding).

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much about Spring-JSON, but I've found Jackson to be an extremely mature and flexible solution. It's well integrated with Spring itself; for example, if you have Jackson on the classpath, you get support for JSON with @ResponseBody-annotated methods. It's reasonably fast, and has good documentation.

Comment: Thanks, right now I saw 4 solutions - spring-json, jackson (delivered with Spring-MVC), FlexJson (delivered with SpringRoo) and gson... After few hours of play with first 3 of them i found that FlexJSON is fastest in setting up, spring-json has best docs and Spring-mvc jackson has working samples on spring svn. However my question is more related to speed, reliability, security etc

Answer (score 0):

For my project, Spring 3.0.5 works seamlessly with Jackson 1.6.3 (jackson-core-asl-1.6.3.jar, jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.3.jar)